# How to remove <Module> ViewQuickcreate default buttons?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

From a QuickCreateView I want to remove the defaults buttons SAVE, CANCEL and FULLFORM. I got to do it modifying the core file `/include/MVC/View/views/view.quickcreate.php` in method `display` by commenting the following lines

```
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['headerTpl'] = $this->headerTpl;
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['footerTpl'] = $this->footerTpl;
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'] = $this->defaultButtons;
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['button_location'] = 'bottom';
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['hidden'] = '<input type="hidden" name="is_ajax_call" value="1" />';
$this->ev->defs['templateMeta']['form']['hidden'] .= '<input type="hidden" name="from_dcmenu" value="1" />';
```

But I want to avoid this. What is the right way to remove default buttons from 
ViewQuickcreate?

Comment: You want to remove all "Quick Create" buttons? from whole CRM?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just need to remove quick create button from Accounts module